# How to sort by national characters in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sorting, collation

I am trying to retrieve items sorted by some field but ordering should take national characters into account - otherwise field that starts with national character are pushed to the bottom of result set. I am using "pl_PL" collation but am not getting proper results.

Consider following example:

```
show client_encoding ;

CREATE DATABASE collate_test;
\connect collate_test;

CREATE TABLE items (name varchar(64) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO items VALUES ('wino');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('ananas');
INSERT INTO items VALUES ('łopata');

SELECT name FROM items ORDER BY name COLLATE "pl_PL";
```

I am getting output:

```
 client_encoding
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

CREATE DATABASE
You are now connected to database "collate_test" as user "lukasz".
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
  name
--------
 ananas
 wino
 łopata
(3 rows)
```

While output of the `select` statement should be:

```
  name
--------
 ananas
 łopata
 wino
(3 rows)
```

(notice that "łopata" should be between "ananas" and "wino")

---

System info:

Postgres 10.4 installed via homebrew on macOS.

```
➜  ~ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.4
➜  ~ uname -a
Darwin Ahadi.local 17.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.7.0: Thu Jun 21 22:53:14 PDT 2018; root:xnu-4570.71.2~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
➜  ~
```

Comment: Which operating system and PostgreSQL version is this?

Comment: Oh, my bad. It's macOS with PostgreSQL 10.4. I've updated initial question.

Comment: Hmm, PostgreSQL uses the operating system's collations, so that would be a MacOS bug... You could try ICU collations.